# Verify if the second character is a letter in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to put a condition in my query where I have a column that should contain second position as an alphabet.

How to achieve this?

I've tried with `_[A-Z]%` in where clause but is not working. I've also tried `[A-Z]%`.

Any inputs please?

Comment: need some sample data as well

Comment: I have a column name worknumber. inside this column I have datas.The datas are in  12 digit format...the worknumber should be in the format in which the second letter should be an  alphabet... how to achieve this? @Mihir Shah

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff am using DB2 database

Answer (score 4):

I think you want mysql query. like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^.[A-Za-z]+$'
```

or sql server

```
select * from table  where  column like '_[a-zA-Z]%'
```

Comment: in the second query where do u give the column name?

Comment: Yes it is given column name

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression matching in your query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `name` REGEXP '^.[a-zA-Z].*';
```

That would match the `name` column from the `test` table against a regex that verifies if the second character is either a lowercase or uppercase alphabet letter.

Also see this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92b72/3) for an example of data it does and doesn't match.

Comment: I tried this but its not working. select WorkOrderNo from Workorder where WorkOrderNo REGXP '^.[a-zA-Z].*'

Answer (score 0):

The use of `'%[A-Z]%'` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can do this using `LIKE`:

```
where col like '_[A-Z]%'
```

For `LIKE` patterns, `_` represents any character.  If the first character needs to be a digit:

```
where col like '[0-9][A-Z]%'
```

EDIT:

The above doesn't work in DB2.  Instead:

```
where substr(col, 2, 1) between 'A' and 'Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with @Gordon Linoff, your ('_[A-Z]%') should work.
if not work, kindly add some sample data with your question.

```
Declare @Table Table
(
    TextCol     Varchar(20)
)

Insert Into @Table(TextCol) Values
    ('23423cvxc43f')
,('2eD97S9')
,('sAgsdsf')
,('3Ss08008')

Select  *
From    @Table As t
Where   t.TextCol Like '_[A-Z]%'
```

Comment: some sample data, please

Comment: its a big query...I have to add this condition in to the big query... am testing it with one sample table but still your code is not working

Comment: not required full query, only screen shot of sample data

Comment: sample data what do u mean? sorry am not getting you... and also how will I add screen shot here